# Correct way of using a windows lib in D?

Tags: binding, d, parallel-port

I'd like to write C bindings for [InpOut32 library](http://www.highrez.co.uk/Downloads/InpOut32/default.htm).

First of all I downloaded [binaries](http://www.highrez.co.uk/scripts/download.asp?package=InpOutBinaries) for this library.

There are three files in it:

- inpout32.lib
- inpout32.h
- inpout32.dll

Here's what i've tried to get D to use this lib.

```
//io.d

extern(C)
{
    void    Out32(short PortAddress, short data);
    short   Inp32(short PortAddress);
}
```

---

```
// test.d 

import std.stdio;
import io;

// parallel port address
short port = 0x0378;

void main()
{
    /* data */
    short data = 0b_00000000;
    Out32(port, data);
}
```

**Compile:** dmd -c test.d io.d **Result:** successfull

**Link:** link test.obj io.obj inpout32.lib

But when I try to link I get this linker error:

> OPTLINK (R) for Win32  Release 8.00.12 Copyright (C) Digital Mars
>
> 1989-2010  All rights reserved.
>
> http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/optlink.html inpout32.lib Offset 00000H
>
> Record Type 0021  Error 138: Module or Dictionary corrupt

The library file probably is in the COFF format. I think `coffimplib` tool is not free, so I used Borland's `coff2omf` tool to OMF format.After converting I still get linker errors like this:

> OPTLINK (R) for Win32  Release 8.00.12
>
> Copyright (C) Digital Mars 1989-2010  All rights reserved.
>
> http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/optlink.html
>
> test.obj(test)
>    Error 42: Symbol Undefined _Out32

Any ideas how to use this lib? Thanks..

---

**Update:** 
Today I read an [interesting article](http://www.gamedev.net/blog/1140/entry-2254003-binding-d-to-c) about creating bindings to C libraries for the D programming language.

Now test.exe works as expected. So far I've done these steps.

**Compile :** dmd -c -g test.d io.d

Thanks [Ali Çehreli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131995/ali-cehreli) for mentioning -g option. After adding -g flag `access violation errors` disappeared.

**Generate OMF import library:** implib -a inpout32.lib inpout32.dll

**Link:** link test.obj io.obj inpout32.lib

After this I'd like to try manually loading DLL's. Thanks for taking the time to answer, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to fiddle with coff2omf or similar tools' flags regarding the leading _ characters (check the lib file to make sure symbols include them).

Alternatively, you may find it easier to generate an OMF import library directly from the .dll, using an implib utility.

Finally, if you only need to use a small number of functions, loading the DLL dynamically using `LoadLibrary` and getting the functions' addresses using `GetProcAddress` will avoid all hassle with .lib files.

Comment: I finally managed to link using a tool to extract a link library from a DLL. This is the implib utility you mentioned above I think. To extract library I used Borland's _implib_ tool with -a option:`implib -a inpout32.lib inpout32.dll` then finally linked it with `link test.obj io.obj inpout32.lib` After executing program I recognized that still I get `Access violation` errors. I don't know this is the case for all Window7 console applications but it runs with this command fine: `Runas /user:Erdem test.exe' Thank you very much for the help :)